# DNASTAR viral-host integration assembly keeps failing

Tags: ngs, assembly, fastq, virus

I have two NGS files from an NGS company corresponding to the sequencing data from a tumor sample as follows:

- TB_7710391_R1.FASTQ.gz
- TB_7710391_R2.FASTQ.gz

I have downloaded the genome for MCPyV as a file called “MCPYV_Sequence.fasta”

I have downloaded the Hg38 as a file called “hg_38.fa”

I have input the host genome as hg_38.fa, the viral genome as “ MCPYV_Sequence.fasta” and the sequence data as both FASTQ files.

I run the assembly in the cloud, and I receive back an error stating that the assembly as failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question needs more detail. What cloud service are you using? How are you using it? Why are you trying to do an assembly? What results are you looking for?